# Find in 2 levels of nested arrays in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

After googling a lot, I can't locate something that can handle this. And it's supposed to be simple, I guess. I've this simple json...

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("555bd34329de3cf232434ef2"),
"clients" : [ 
    {
        "Client1" : {
            "positions" : [ 
                {
                    "systemId" : "xxx1",
                    "type" : "alfa"
                },
                {
                    "systemId" : "xxx2",
                    "type" : "bravo"
                },
                {
                    "systemId" : "xxx3",
                    "type" : "charlie"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Client2" : {
            "positions" : [ 
                {
                    "systemId" : "xxx4",
                    "type" : "alfa"
                },
                {
                    "systemId" : "xxx5",
                    "type" : "bravo"
                },
                {
                    "systemId" : "xxx6",
                    "type" : "charlie"
                }
            ]
        } 
    }
]
}
```

And I'm trying to perform a query based on the {systemId} into positions array that's inside an array that's inside another array. I can easily use find() in a single level array. But at this time I need an additional depth and I really facing difficulty. Can someone give me a help ?

tyvm !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to find out `Client1.positions` with `systemId`  and `Client2.positions` with `systemId` use following aggregation :

```
db.collectionName.aggregate([
    {
        "$unwind": "$clients"
    },
    {
        "$unwind": "$clients.Client1.positions"
    },
    {
        "$unwind": "$clients.Client2.positions"
    },
    {
        "$match": {
            "clients.Client1.positions.systemId": "xxx1",
            "clients.Client2.positions.systemId": "xxx4"
        }
    }
]).pretty()
```

If you want to find out only `Client1` then remove `"$unwind": "$clients.Client2.positions"` and in match `"clients.Client2.positions.systemId": "xxx4"`

Answer (score 1):

As per your sample data, `clients` contains different objects like `Client1` `Client2` etc which further contains `positions` array of objects. In this case to find `systemId`, You need to use [$elemMatch](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) as following:

```
db.collection.find({
  "clients": {
    $elemMatch: {
        "Client2.positions": {
            $elemMatch: {
                "systemId": "xxx4"
            }
        }
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Yes, but in this way...I supposed to know who is the client. My only criteria will be the systemId. So it's supposed to be something like clients : $elemMatch : { *.positions : { $elemMatch : { systemId: xxx4}}}.

Comment: You should know `Client2`. Also it is bad practice to have dynamic names as a `key` in your schema. If possible, you can change `Client1,2` as `clientName: Client1` etc. It will be easy to handle in query.